Oqtane Module Development - Entity Framework
I'm writing an Oqtane module and I'm working off of the standard source code template that's generated from the platform.  I can't get any traditional entity framework commands for things like migrations to work.
It creates a standard initial migration but you can't run it - I get the error

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'Baydn.Module.Contact.Repository.QuickLinksContext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Oqtane.Repository.IDBContextDependencies' while attempting to activate 'Baydn.Module.Contact.Repository.QuickLinksContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

How can I get commands like update and migration(s) to work?

Could you show the code you are using that results in this error?
